# Replace one command with another during make build

Tags: make, build

I build some application with `cmake` and `make all package` commands.
During the build the `rpmbuild` program is implicitly called by `cpack` as part of the build.
I need it to call `setarch i686 rpmbuild` instead of just `rpmbuild`.
How do I accomplish this in a neat way without ugly hacks?

Answer (score 0):

Use a shell alias. For example:

alias rpmbuild="setarch `uname -m` rpmbuild"

Or whatever you need on the right side.

Comment: Does an alias work from within cpack????

Comment: It didn't work for me.